# window.myFunction = myFunction vs. onclick="mySecondFunction()"

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I've got an HTML page that looks somewhat like this

```
...
<h1>Title</h1>
<button id="myFirstButton">my first button</button>
<button id="mySecondButton" onclick="myClickFunction()">my second button</button>
<script src="myJavascript.js"></script>
...
```

And the myJavascript.js looks like this

```
...
window.myClickFunction = myClickFunction;
document.getElementById("myFirstButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
   console.log("clicked on first button!");
});

function myClickFunction() {
  console.log("clicked on second button!");
}
...
```

This code works fine. But I've got a couple questions.

1. What is the difference?
2. In which cases should I use which approach?
3. Why does `myClickFunction()` not work when I don't use the `window.myClickFunction = myClickFunction`?

Comment: `myClickFunction()` doesn't "work" because it never runs. You need to call it `myClickFunction();` or attach as event listener `document.getElementById("myFirstButton").addEventListener("click", myClickFunction);`

Comment: @SonNguyen It runs when clicking mySecondButton

Comment: More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Comment: Yes right way should be `onclick="myClickFunction()` or function won't run. just my typo. To answer the question, there's no big difference: generally you should prefer to use js to attach event rather than define it in HTML, to provide separation of concern between markup and behavior. Another thing is that JS addEventListener has the benefit of attaching as many handlers as you like, while you only have one `onclick` property (though you can chain many calls within it which could become too long

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function myFunction in the global scope, it IS window.myFunction so

`window.myClickFunction = myClickFunction;` is the same as doing `myfunction=myFunction` it has no effect whatsoever.

To answer #3, we need to see more code. Perhaps you did NOT declare myClickFunction in global scope but inside an event handler or something

For example

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  function myFunction() { console.log("hello"); }
})

function myFunction1() { 
  console.log("hello from myFunction1"); 
  myFunction(); // not in window scope
}

myFunction1()
```